# Creating accessible crosswords

Tags: puzzle-creation, crosswords

Often, crosswords* posted to Puzzling have at least one of the grid or clues in an image. For visually impaired, blind, and/or screen-reader using people, or those who can't see images for some other reason (firewall, bad internet connection, etc.) this can make the puzzles inaccessible and impossible to enjoy.

I am aware of [tools for solving crosswords in an accessible way](https://www.perkinselearning.org/technology/blog/aph-accessible-crossword-puzzle-app-review), however, it is site policy to ["try to ensure that puzzles are entirely contained within [Puzzling]"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6506/), so I would like some good way to host an on-site accessible version. If this method extends to non-rectangular grids, that's wonderful. But, I am mainly concerned with the standard grid with black and white squares. The clues of course should also be presented in an accessible format.

**How can I make an accessible crossword puzzle, meant for posting on Puzzling Stack Exchange?**

* <sub>here "crosswords" refers to any type of crossword - so "regular", or cryptic or anything else. I assume the methods transfer.</sub>

Comment: should this be a Meta post?

Comment: @BenjaminWang, nope, Puzzling is for questions which are about puzzles or which are puzzles, it's just that the latter is more common

Comment: Could you add some example questions here to show the sort of one's you mean, I went looking myself, but there's a lot of wild and unusual crosswords on this site.

Comment: I can't use Imgur.

Answer (score -4):

Grids can be displayed using a fixed-width font (preformatted text). Here is the top portion of a recently posted crossword, because I'm too lazy to finish the whole grid. :o)

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |   |2  |   |3  |   |4  |   |5  |   |6  |   |   |   |###|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |###|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|###|###|###|
|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|###|###|###|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|7  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |8  |   |###|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |###|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |###|   |###|###|###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|9  |
|   |###|   |###|###|###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |###|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|10 |   |   |   |11 |   |###|12 |   |   |   |   |   |###|   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |###|   |   |   |   |   |   |###|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Does this work for screen readers?

Comment: @bobble I have no experience with screen readers. The transcription may come through with varying levels of difficulty, or not at all.

Comment: I'm really interested in making a crossword work well with a screen reader, so if you could research in that direction and edit your answer, that'd be wonderful

Comment: @bobble Then it seems to me like this is more of a question about screen readers, rather than about puzzles? I don't think being a puzzle expert would be particularly helpful in answering this.

Comment: @bobble Why should I do such research for you? If you have a screen reader, it is a simple matter to see what it makes of my post.

Comment: @Deusovi a screen reader expert with no knowledge of puzzles would be completely lost in understanding how a crossword puzzle would be structured and formatted. It needs expertise in botg.

Comment: @DanielMathias if bobble was able to do so, I'm sure they would have already self-answered. I don't think it's unreasonable for an answerer to consider all points in a question before answering? You ask "Why should I do such research for you? " But my counter is, why would you post if you don't know how to answer correctly?

Comment: @PuzzleFerret The question did not specifically request a solution that works well with screen readers. It asks more generally for a solution that avoids images, which I offered. I do not think it is unreasonable to expect bobble to be able to determine if an answer fits a specific need.

Comment: @daniel "For visually impaired, blind, and/or **screen-reader using people**, or those who can't see images for some other reason " it's right there.

Comment: @PuzzleFerret "Often, crosswords ... have at least one ... image. For [some users] this can make the puzzles inaccessible and impossible to enjoy." Screen-reader users were included in general, but my previous comment stands.

Comment: @PuzzleFerret Would they be "completely lost"? I think it's pretty straightforward to understand how a crossword puzzle looks, even if you're not a puzzle expert. Most people know what crossword puzzles *are*.